# Can I group DateTime type data in PivotGrid of DevExpress during runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, devexpress, pivot-table

I have a PivotGrid (DevExpress) within WPF and bind the DataSource to an IList that contains objects of which there are several properties of type DateTime. I want the end-user to choose during runtime which of those DateTime fields the user wants to group by Year, Month, or Day. Is that possible?

I understand that I can provide DateTime groupings programmatically but as there are several DateTime fields it would be quite tedious and unnecessary if the end-user can choose which DateTime field to group and how to group it during runtime.

Can you please guide me how to do that?

I have the following:

```
  <dxdo:LayoutControlItem ItemWidth="1*">
                                <dxpg:PivotGridControl MaxHeight="800" MaxWidth="800" DataSource="{Binding AllChildOrders}" DataSourceChanged="PivotGridControl_OnDataSourceChanged">
                            </dxpg:PivotGridControl>
                        </dxdo:LayoutControlItem>
```

and in code behind:

```
private void PivotGridControl_OnDataSourceChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pivotTable = sender as PivotGridControl;
        pivotTable.RetrieveFields();
    }
```

The above code works and the pivot table displays all available fields during runtime, including the fields of type DateTime. I do not want to programmatically specify which fields to group in particular ways but let the end-user during runtime choose how and which field to group. Possible?

Alternatively I could imagine to programmatically create sub-groupings as follows: How can I accomplish the following?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**0. Pre-generate groups**

If you don't want to programmatically specify which fields to group, then you can pregenerate groups for each `DateTime` field, so user can choose between fields itself and groups of fields.
Here is example:

```
private void PivotGridControl_DataSourceChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pivotTable = sender as PivotGridControl;
    pivotTable.Groups.Clear();
    pivotTable.RetrieveFields();

    var dateTimeFields = pivotTable.Fields.Where(item => item.DataType == typeof(DateTime)).ToList();

    foreach (var field in dateTimeFields)
    {
        var group = new PivotGridGroup();
        group.Add(new PivotGridField() { FieldName = field.FieldName, Caption = field.Caption + " (year)", GroupInterval = FieldGroupInterval.DateYear });
        group.Add(new PivotGridField() { FieldName = field.FieldName, Caption = field.Caption + " (month)", GroupInterval = FieldGroupInterval.DateMonth });
        group.Add(new PivotGridField() { FieldName = field.FieldName, Caption = field.Caption + " (day)", GroupInterval = FieldGroupInterval.DateDay });

        foreach (var groupField in group)
            pivotTable.Fields.Add(groupField);

        pivotTable.Groups.Add(group);
    }
}
```

Here is screenshot of example:
[image: Screenshot]

**1. Create sub-groupins**

You can create sub-groupings by using [`PivotGridField.DisplayFolder`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfPivotGridPivotGridField_DisplayFoldertopic) property.
Here is example:

```
private void PivotGridControl_DataSourceChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pivotTable = sender as PivotGridControl;
    pivotTable.RetrieveFields();

    var dateTimeFields = pivotTable.Fields.Where(item => item.DataType == typeof(DateTime)).ToList();

    foreach (var field in dateTimeFields)
    {
        var fieldYear = new PivotGridField()
        {
            FieldName = field.FieldName,
            Caption = field.Caption + " (year)",
            GroupInterval = FieldGroupInterval.DateYear,
            Visible = false,
            DisplayFolder = field.Caption
        };

        var fieldMonth = new PivotGridField()
        {
            FieldName = field.FieldName,
            Caption = field.Caption + " (month)",
            GroupInterval = FieldGroupInterval.DateMonth,
            Visible = false,
            DisplayFolder = field.Caption
        };

        var fieldDay = new PivotGridField()
        {
            FieldName = field.FieldName,
            Caption = field.Caption + " (day)",
            GroupInterval = FieldGroupInterval.DateDay,
            Visible = false,
            DisplayFolder = field.Caption
        };

        pivotTable.Fields.Add(fieldYear);
        pivotTable.Fields.Add(fieldMonth);
        pivotTable.Fields.Add(fieldDay);
    }
}
```

Here is result:
[image: Result]

**2. Customize popup menu**

You can add commands to field popup menu which allows user to change group interval. For this you can use [`PivotGridControl.PopupMenuShowing`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfPivotGridPivotGridControl_PopupMenuShowingtopic) event and [`PopupMenuShowingEventArgs.Customizations`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfPivotGridPopupMenuShowingEventArgs_Customizationstopic) property to customize menu.
Here is example:

```
private void PivotGridControl_DataSourceChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pivotTable = sender as PivotGridControl;
    pivotTable.Groups.Clear();
    pivotTable.RetrieveFields();
}

private void PivotGridControl_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.MenuType != PivotGridMenuType.Header)
        return;

    var fieldHeader = e.TargetElement as FieldHeader;

    if (fieldHeader == null)
        return;

    var field = fieldHeader.Content as PivotGridField;

    if (field == null || (field.Group != null && field.Group.IndexOf(field) > 0))
        return;

    var groupInterval = field.GroupInterval;

    if (groupInterval == FieldGroupInterval.Default && field.DataType != typeof(DateTime))
        return;

    var dateTimeIntervals = new List<FieldGroupInterval>(new FieldGroupInterval[]
    {
        FieldGroupInterval.DateYear,
        FieldGroupInterval.DateQuarter,
        FieldGroupInterval.DateMonth,
        FieldGroupInterval.DateDay,
        FieldGroupInterval.Hour,
        FieldGroupInterval.Minute,
        FieldGroupInterval.Second,
        FieldGroupInterval.DateWeekOfYear,
        FieldGroupInterval.DateWeekOfMonth,
        FieldGroupInterval.DateDayOfYear,
        FieldGroupInterval.DateDayOfWeek,
        FieldGroupInterval.Date,
        FieldGroupInterval.Default
    });

    if (!dateTimeIntervals.Contains(groupInterval))
        return;

    var pivotTable = sender as PivotGridControl;

    var subMenu = new BarSubItem() { };
    subMenu.Content = "Set group interval";

    if (field.Group == null)
    {
        var button = new BarButtonItem() { Content = "Year - Month - Date" };
        button.ItemClick += (s, eventArgs) =>
        {
            pivotTable.BeginUpdate();

            var group = field.Tag as PivotGridGroup;

            if (group == null)
            {
                if (groupInterval != FieldGroupInterval.Default)
                    field.Caption = field.Caption.Replace(" (" + groupInterval + ")", string.Empty);

                group = new PivotGridGroup();
                group.Add(new PivotGridField() { FieldName = field.FieldName, Caption = field.Caption + " (year)", GroupInterval = FieldGroupInterval.DateYear, Tag = field, Area = field.Area, AreaIndex = field.AreaIndex });
                group.Add(new PivotGridField() { FieldName = field.FieldName, Caption = field.Caption + " (month)", GroupInterval = FieldGroupInterval.DateMonth });
                group.Add(new PivotGridField() { FieldName = field.FieldName, Caption = field.Caption + " (day)", GroupInterval = FieldGroupInterval.DateDay });

                foreach (var groupField in group)
                    pivotTable.Fields.Add(groupField);

                pivotTable.Groups.Add(group);

                group.Tag = field;
            }
            else
            {
                var yearField = group[0];

                yearField.Area = field.Area;
                yearField.AreaIndex = field.AreaIndex;
                yearField.ShowInCustomizationForm = true;
            }

            field.Visible = false;
            field.ShowInCustomizationForm = false;

            pivotTable.EndUpdate();
        };

        subMenu.Items.Add(button);
    }

    foreach (var dateTimeInterval in dateTimeIntervals.Where(item => item != groupInterval))
    {
        var button = new BarButtonItem() { Content = dateTimeInterval, Tag = field };
        subMenu.Items.Add(button);

        button.ItemClick += (s, eventArgs) =>
        {
            pivotTable.BeginUpdate();

            var group = field.Group;

            if (group != null)
            {
                var yearField = field;
                field = yearField.Tag as PivotGridField;

                field.Area = yearField.Area;
                field.AreaIndex = yearField.AreaIndex;
                field.ShowInCustomizationForm = true;

                yearField.Visible = false;
                yearField.ShowInCustomizationForm = false;
            }
            else if (groupInterval != FieldGroupInterval.Default)
                field.Caption = field.Caption.Replace(" (" + groupInterval + ")", string.Empty);

            field.GroupInterval = dateTimeInterval;

            if (dateTimeInterval != FieldGroupInterval.Default)
                field.Caption += " (" + dateTimeInterval + ")";

            pivotTable.EndUpdate();
        };
    }

    e.Customizations.Add(subMenu);
}
```

Here is result:
[image: Result with sub-menu]

Comment: I appreciate your effort and I see how this works but that is exactly what I try to avoid because I will have 4 to 5 different DateTime properties/fields and pre-grouping each would create 20 different fields just for the DateTime fields. Would you know whether DevExpress offers runtime functionality to group?

Comment: But one other potential solution could be to have the sub-grouped DateTime fields arranged as child items. I attached a screenshot from the WPF DevExpress demo to illustrate. How can I have those fields displayed in the same way as in the attached image?

Comment: @MattWolf DevExpress does not offer such functionality to group. Take a look at update of my answer for sub-groups.

Comment: @MattWolf Also you can customize popup menu. I have update my answer with this approach.

Comment: would you know whether I also have to programmatically add fields to average data or calculate their standard deviation or can an end-user do that on the fly?

Comment: @MattWolf There are something like this in `WinForms` fields: [`PivotGridFieldOptions.AllowRunTimeSummaryChange`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridFieldOptions_AllowRunTimeSummaryChangetopic) property. I think, for WPF you can make it by your own.

Comment: will take a look but its sounds a bit disappointing. I asked a new question regarding this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554660/devexpress-pivotgrid-can-data-be-averaged-or-standard-deviation-calculated-duri). Point is, I feel the inflexibility to do anything during run-time kind of defeats the whole purpose of a pivot grid. If all summary statistics and groupings have to be prepared beforehand then this is more like a report than a dynamic pivot table. I need something that gives the end-user freedom and flexibility without having to precalc every eventuality.

Comment: ...just for the DateTime groupings I have 4 or 5 fields and I need to programmatically prepare groupings for second, minute, hour, day, week, month, quarter, year. That is alone up to 40 fields, not including a single summary statistic. I am thinking about just opening Excel and populating the data table in Excel and using a more flexible pivot table if summary statistics cannot be freely specified during runtime. Btw, I expressed my disappointment towards the PivotGrid control by Devexpress, not your answer and appreciated effort to help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MattWolf `PivotGrid` allows you to programmatically change groupings and summary statistics in runtime, but there are no such UI, so you need to make it by yourself.

Comment: I am confused when you said "allows you to programmatically change groupings and summary statistics in runtime". I do not want to have to prepare any groupings or summary statistics in code. I want to bind the control to a data table (or IList in my case) and let the end-user choose how he wants to group or what summary statistics are needed. Am I correct that PivotGrid of Devexpress does not offer such functionality? I do appreciate your answer and a workaround but it simply does not work for me because I would end up with hundreds of fields when including groupings and summary stats.

Comment: @MattWolf Yes, you are correct. Programmaticaly you can change all of this, for example this code `someField.GroupInterval = FieldGroupInterval.Date;` will change the `GroupInterval` of exsiting field without creating of new field. But if you want to let the end-user choose how he wants to group or what summary statistics are needed, then you need to develop this functionality for user.